# How can I search for 2 different values on different columns on excel?

Tags: database, excel

I use a database that has 3 fields: "house number" "address" and "city" which has thousands of addresses on it.

If I need to find '345 High Street' I'd need to use the Find & Replace feature, type in 'High Street' & then keep clicking next until I'd finally get to '345' due to High street being so common with so many different high street addresses. I couldn't search '345 High Street' due to the house number being in a separate field.

Is there any way I could search 2 values on the same row to appear?

Thanks and I hope this all makes sense

Comment: Is your intent to find these manually or programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

Use a helper column.

With house number in column A and address in column B, row 1 has labels, start in row 2 with the formula

=A2&" "&B2

Copy down.  Now search for '345 High Street' in the helper column.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to looking for a [Two-column Lookup](http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/two-column-lookup.html) from what I can gather.

Let's take up a small example here:

- Let the data in question be as below:

  [image]
- Use a construct as given below and one the formula has been entered, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to evaluate the array formula:

  [image]
- The result will be as follows:

  [image]